# How to get the type of a variable defined in a protobuf message?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to do some 'translation' from protobuf files to Objective-C classes using Python. For example, given the protobuf message:

```
message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
}
```

I want to translate it into an objc class:

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int ID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *email; 
@end
```

The key point is to acquire every property's name and type. For example, 'optional string email' in the protobuf message, its name is 'email', type is 'string', so it should be NSString *email in objective-c. I followed the official tutorial, wrote an addressbook.proto just the same as the one in the tutorial and compiled it. Then I wrote my python code:

```
import addressbook_pb2 as addressbook

p = addressbook.Person()
all_fields = p.DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name
# print "all fields: %s" %all_fields
field_keys = all_fields.keys()
# print "all keys: %s" %field_keys

for key in field_keys:
    one_field = all_fields[key]
    print one_field.label
```

This just gave me:

```
1
2
3
2
```

So I guess label is not what I need, while field_keys is just the list of names that I expect. I tried some other words, and did some search on the web, but didn't find the right answer.

If there's no way to acquire the type, I have another thought, which is to read and analyze every line of the protobuf source file in a pure 'Pythonic' way, but I really don't want to do this if its not necessary.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What are you meaning by "the type"? What sort of thing are you expecting? There is a " wire type" that describes how something is packed in the data, and there may the "proto" declared type, and the runtime type of your chosen platform... Which so you mean?

Comment: By 'type' I mean 'string, int32' in the protobuf message, and name is 'name, id, email'. I want to get the type 'string' for example, to translate it to 'NSString' in objecitve-c.

Comment: is there not a `type` member of some kind? by comparison to the `c` version: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#FieldDescriptor.Type.details

Comment: Thank you! Why didn't I find this? I guess it's because I am new to protobuf and google's python protobuf document is much more ugly than the C++ version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Marc's answer, I figured out some solution. This is just a thought, but it's a huge step for me.

Python code:

```
import addressbook_pb2 as addressbook

typeDict = {"1":"CGFloat", "2":"CGFloat", "3":"NSInteger", "4":"NSUinteger", "5":"NSInteger", "8":"BOOL", "9":"NSString", "13":"NSUinteger", "17":"NSInteger", "18":"NSInteger"}

attrDict = {"CGFloat":"assign", "NSInteger":"assign", "NSUinteger":"assign", "BOOL":"assign", "NSString":"copy"}

p = addressbook.Person()
all_fields = p.DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name
field_keys = all_fields.keys()
for key in field_keys:
    one_field = all_fields[key]
    typeNumStr = str(one_field.type)
    className = typeDict.get(typeNumStr, "NSObject")
    attrStr = attrDict.get(className, "retain")
    propertyStr = "@property (nonatomic, %s) %s *%s" %(attrStr, className, key)
    print propertyStr
```

For the addressbook example, it prints:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *email
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *phone
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger *id
```

Not the final solution, but it means a lot. Thank you, Marc!

Answer (score 3):

The [FieldDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.descriptor.FieldDescriptor-class.html) class has a `message_type` member which, if a composite field, is a descriptor of the message type contained in this field.  Otherwise, this is None.

Combine this with iterating through a dictionary of `DESCRIPTORS` means you can get the **name** and **type** of composite and non-composite (raw) fields.

```py
import addressbook_pb2 as addressbook
DESCRIPTORS = addressbook.Person.DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name

for (field_name, field_descriptor) in DESCRIPTORS.items():

    if field_descriptor.message_type:
        # Composite field
        print(field_name, field_descriptor.message_type.name)
    else:
        # Raw type
        print(field_name, field_descriptor.type)
        # TYPE_DOUBLE
        # TYPE_FLOAT 
        # TYPE_INT64 
        # TYPE_UINT64
        # TYPE_INT32 
        # TYPE_FIXED64
        # TYPE_FIXED32
        # TYPE_BOOL  
        # TYPE_STRING
        # TYPE_GROUP
        # TYPE_MESSAGE
        # TYPE_BYTES
        # TYPE_UINT32
        # TYPE_ENUM
        # TYPE_SFIXED32
        # TYPE_SFIXED64
        # TYPE_SINT32
        # TYPE_SINT64
        # MAX_TYPE
```

The raw types are class attributes; https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/descriptor.py